# Why a program written in the Intel assembly language cannot be executed on the PowerPC processor?

Tags: computer-architecture

Why are these two architectures incompatible?

Comment: For the same reason that Chinese is incomprehensible to somebody who only speaks English, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3):

The PowerPC and Intel architectures vary individually in their various iterations, and are in many ways incompatible. This means the instruction sets for each will not be compatible, as well.

There are a lot of reasons why any two given architectures will not be compatible (register number/size, memory allocation schemes, processing unit differences, bus width, etc.), but at a basic level the instruction sets for the two architectures are different. You can look at the differences between them; using an iteration of each at random, the [PowerPC instruction set](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/library/es-ppcbook1.zip) and the [Intel instruction set](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) have different opcodes. So, even within different generations of an individual architecture family there is likely to be some incompatibility between any given assembly program, as the underlying opcodes can be different.

So, this question is a bit like asking why isn't someone who knows a human language x able to understand an animal call y? The underlying languages and structures of both systems are essentially different, while sharing some functionality at a high level. There are examples where the two share functionality and can overlap or communicate (honey birds in Africa and people who are able to call to them, people who can practice calls for various species, human use of artificial calls, etc.), but generally they are only vaguely similar in that they are both "languages," and one would not expect them to be 100% compatible.

Comment: Mnemonics are irrelevant to the compiled code. Assembly language is just another programming language, so you're free to write an assembler that calls the ADD instruction "PLUS" or "MULT" or anything you want. It would be super-confusing, but it wouldn't affect the binary.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Mnemonics (while, yes, are ~arbitrarily assigned, like all languages) are a reflection of opcode, which are a reflection of the underlying binary, no? So, wouldn't it follow that an instruction set with floating point mnemonics and another with none, is likely to indicate the architecture underlying the latter wouldn't be compatible (may not have an FPU, may implement an alternate scheme to represent rational numbers, etc.) with the former? I'm not trying to be difficult, just want to know your thoughts.

Comment: Mnemonics are purely an aid to the programmer, because it's easier to remember "MOV" than "instruction 56" or whatever. The point is whether or not you have an architecture with floating-point **instructions**. The CPU never sees the mnemonic: only the op-codes.

Comment: Hmm, I agree with what you're saying, but it seems like a bit of a distinction without a difference. It varies, of course, but the mnemonics generally correspond to the opcodes, no? Isn't saying the CPU only "sees" opcodes not assembly a bit like saying a CPU only sees plus or minus values of voltages, not binary?

Comment: The CPU executes programs by receiving a stream of opcodes. If CPU A believes that opcode 1 means "add two numbers" and CPU B believes that opcode 1 means "multiply two numbers" then you can't execute a program intended for A on B. The mnemonics are just a programming language. Tomorrow, Intel could declare "From now on, our assembler uses this new set of mnemonics, which are completely different from the current ones." They would not need to change the CPU at all. Programs written with the old mnemonics would continue to work identically to how they worked before.

Comment: So, no, it is not a distinction without a difference. The mnemonics are something the CPU never sees. They're not a different perspective (like binary versus voltages): they are literally irrelevant to the actual execution of the program. They're just names. Would the Beatles be the same band if they changed their names to Jim, Bob, Fred and Norm? Yes. It would be annoying to talk about them but they'd still play exactly the same music and you wouldn't be able to tell that they'd changed their names just by listening to them.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidRicherby! After your comments I went back to my computer architecture text and did a bit of research/reading about the relationship between mnemonics and opcodes. You're absolutely right, they are irrelevant in terms of the underlying architecture. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You're welcome -- glad to be able to help.